# Remove vertical space between lines

Tags: line-spacing, line, vertical

I'm new to LaTeX. I completely want to remove the vertical space between two consecutive lines in a paragraph. Let me show you what I mean.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{0}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}

\begin{document}

nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn  

\begin{table}[h]

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline a&a&a\\
b&b&b\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn nnnnn 

\end{document}
```

In this code, even though the baselinestretch is 0, there seems to be a tiny vertical gap between to consecutive lines.

[image: sample]

But when the arraystretch for the table is 0, there is no gap between the two rows of the table.

How should I remove this vertical space from two consecutive lines in a paragraph?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add

```
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}
```

hopefully your real example is some special codes not human readable text!

Comment: Wouldn't that apply for the entire document? Is there a local fix?

Comment: @EduardoReis its a local setting like a font change so local to the current group or environment